# RTS and DTR High on serialport open

Tags: serial-port, tcl

Can anyone tell me how to stop RTS and DTR turning on when a serialport is opened with wish85?

The attached image shows what happens at turn.

This doesn't seem to happen when you open a serialport with visual studio in C#.[image]

In TCL, I have used

```
set com [open com7: w]
fconfigure $com -ttycontrol {DTR 0}
fconfigure $com -ttycontrol {RTS 0}
```

and in C# its just

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM7", 300);
sp.Open();  // to open the port
```

Comment: Are you using RTS/CTS flow control or XOn/XOff in C#?  Can you show how you open the serial port in C# and in TCL.

Comment: Morning cup I don't know how to put code in comments properly but in tcl I have used: set com [open com7: w]
fconfigure $com -ttycontrol {DTR 0}
fconfigure $com -ttycontrol {RTS 0} and in C# its just SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM7", 300); then you open the port with sp.Open();

Comment: I have modified your question for you.  Please check that that is what you wanted to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the default is to set everything to 0.  For handshakes, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.handshake?view=netframework-4.7.2 , 0=no handshake.

If you look at the wiki page for tcl on serial ports, under handshake, it says *that there is no default handshake configuration: it depends on your OS.*

Presumably, the default is RTS/CTS.  If you do not want any handshake then specify a handshake of none.  Unfortunately, in tcl, you can't query this - it is a write only value.